# How to store data inside mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

js and mongodb.I have created a model file named models like the one given below

```
 User = new Schema({
        username : String
      , password : String
      , created_at : Date
 });
 mongoose.model('User', User);
 exports.defineModels = defineModels;
```

In app.js i have called the defineModels like this:

```
var models = require('./models'),

models.defineModels(mongoose, function() {
  app.User = User = mongoose.model('User');
  db = mongoose.connect(app.set('db-uri'));
})
```

I can't call save method directly on User or can I?
i want to save data in User what could be the function for the same.any answer will be appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want, you should have something like this:

```
var user = new User({username: 'Name', password: 'unsecure'});
user.save();
```

There are a few things odd with your code, so I highly suggest going over a tutorial that uses express and mongoose to create a sample site (most likely you can find a blog).

Here is one I made: https://github.com/mathrawka/node-express-starter

Good luck!

Comment: ouch. I updated the link to something i made actually. Let me know if you have any feedback!